# cocoa:Click on the event to re- load a link to how to do?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

[image]
button1 pressed google site is opened. button2 pressed youtube site is opened

Prepares the receiver for service after it has been loaded from an Interface Builder archive, or nib file.webview loading a web page

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.youtube.com";
    [[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];
}
```

Click on the event to re- load a link to how to do ?

```
- (IBAction)menuButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.google.com";
    [[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];
}
```

Comment: I dont if you want to reload the _same webpage_ on button click, then simply use `[_yourwebview_ reload];` But for this dont define url-string 2times as u did. It must be accessible in all methods, may be u can declare it publicly.

Comment: I did not clearly described .Add a picture to increase understanding .

Comment: yes your picture describes quite well. I would like to see the action- code u wrote for these two buttons. I guess it must be same. Again I would like to know, do u want like if user presses the same button multiple times it should reload the same webpage.?

Comment: Reload the page，Click the button to load another page.Are re- loaded

Comment: May be there is some communication-gap due to english wording. Reload stands for 'loading the same webpage'. But u said, u want to open another webpage, in which case url will also change. right? if yes then url checking is obvious.!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10799/discussion-between-hp-ios-coder-and-)